# If the probability of an event $A$ is $1$, and $B$ is any event, then $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Tags: probability, independence

> If the probability of an event $A$ is $1$, and $B$ is any event, then
>   $A$ and $B$ are independent.

This seems intuitively true. If we know for sure that $A$ happens, this does not give information about $B$.

However, I am not able to prove it, although I think it must be quite easy to prove.

So given is that $P(A) =1$, and now we must prove that $P(B) = P(A)P(B) = P(A \cap B)$ and it suffices to show that $P(A \cap B) \geq P(B)$, since $A \cap B \subseteq B$

Comment: Hint: $B=(A\cap B)\cup (A^c\cap B)$.  This is a disjoint union.

Comment: @Stijn two events of probability $1$ are independent in the probability sense

Comment: @Stijn Using the definition of independence tells you that the events are independent in this case, although it's counterintuitive.  The reason is that $A$ is almost the entire event space.

Comment: @Stijn: You could say that you choose a real number uniformly from the interval $[0,10]$, and let $A$ and $B$ both be the events that an integer is not chosen.  They would still count as being independent in a probability sense

Comment: @Henry Ok, thanks! I was afraid it'd be something like that.. not the most intuitive choice of wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P(A)P(B)=1 \times P(B)=P(B)=P(A\cap B)+P(A^c \cap B) = P(A\cap B)+0=P(A\cap B)$$

Answer (score 1):

The mathematics is straight forward but intuitively any event happening with probability $1$ is independent from any other event despite the characteristics of that.

Answer (score 0):

If $P(A)=1$, then $A$ is the sample space. Hence:
$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(B)}{1}=P(B).$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $A,B$ are events such that $P(A) = 1$. Consider $P(A \cap B)$. Since $P(A) = 1 = P(S)$, where $S$ is the sample space, we have $A = S$. As such, $B \subset S$ and so $P(A\cap B) = P(B) = 1\cdot P(B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$. Thus, $A,B$ are independent events.

Comment: I think this is wrong. An event can be a proper subset of the sample space with probability 1.

Comment: For example, take $\Omega := \{1,2,3,4,5,6, \dots, 12,13\}$ and consider the probability experiment "Throw two dices and count the sum of the outcomes". Then, the probability of sum a 13 is 0.